# How does a firefighter "recover" after being knocked down?

Tags: flash-point

In the Experienced rules, it says that a firefighter that is Knocked Down (by fire advancing to their location) is placed on the nearest ambulance parking spot.  It also says that they must "visit the ambulance to recover".

Is this just adding the "story" behind why they end up in that spot?  Or is it meant to be literal, that they cannot take other actions until they (or someone else) radio the ambulance to that location?  We decided to take it literally, since it seemed to add a bit more "cost" to being knocked down (otherwise it can actually be advantageous at times), but I couldn't find anything concrete one way or the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be pretty explicit in the version of the rules I have, found [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CEQQFjAC&url=http://www.indieboardsandcards.com/fpfrenglishrules.php&ei=guliUdWjH4PnqQGg_oCYDg&usg=AFQjCNE77GLDCb3GKZPPozo0KQuQ1gERoA&sig2=m1Fu8idbK6d94WvBaZR4Aw&bvm=bv.44770516,d.aWM). Under Knocked Down in the Experienced Rules, it very specifically states:

> When a Firefighter is Knocked Down, the Firefighter is placed in one of the two spaces of the Ambulance's current Parking Spot.

My interpretation of this is that the Firefighter has to go to where the Ambulance is parked, since the Ambulance can only have one current Parking Spot when a Firefighter is knocked down. So you shouldn't have to get the Ambulance moved to where the Firefighter goes because the Firefighter should already be going right to the Ambulance.

Comment: Ah, looks like I was accidentally reading the Family Rules version of Knocked Down.  Definitely clear, though it still seems like a pretty light penalty (that might even help in some cases).